# Getting angle between two points in 2D game, problem when moving camera

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development, angle

I decided to ask question here because I have problem that I think I can't solve myself.
I'm trying to make 2D Game that is RPG, You run around and do stuff.

For that i need to know which direciton player is looking, Player is ofc. looking in direction of mouse, i made function and it's... kinda working but not always, when Camera XY is set to 0,0 angle calculation is made properly. But as soon as i move camera away from 0,0 it's behavior become weird, i cam move Player and Camera separetly ( in case i need cutscenes )

Here is my current code that display 140pixels long line from player position to Mouse position

```
    qAngle = qGetAngle2( // Angle between 2 points ( Player Position + Camera )
                qVec2d{qMouse.x+Camera.x,qMouse.y+Camera.y}, // Mouse + Camera XY
                qVec2d{Shelly.x+Camera.x,Shelly.y+Camera.y});// Player + Camera XY
    Angle = qAngle; // only converting Int to StringInt for debug display
    
    ShellyWindow.qDraw_Line( // Drawing line
                Shelly.x+Camera.x, // Player X + Camera ( start point X )
                Shelly.y+Camera.y, // Player Y + Camera ( start point Y )
                (sin( 0.01744 * qAngle )*140)+(Camera.x+Shelly.x), // End point X
                (cos( 0.01744 * qAngle )*140)+(Camera.y+Shelly.y), // End point Y
                0x00FF00 ); // color
```

I have no idea what should i do... from my point of view logic is 100% fine

This code above works for as long as im not moving camera anywhere...
This is how im moving things around, XS means "Speed", X/Y is just position

```
// moving player XY Speed
    if( qKey_a.Push )Shelly.xs -= 0.11;
    if( qKey_d.Push )Shelly.xs += 0.11;
    if( qKey_w.Push )Shelly.ys -= 0.11;
    if( qKey_s.Push )Shelly.ys += 0.11;

// Moving Camera XY position
    if( qKey_f.Push )Camera.x += 5;
    if( qKey_h.Push )Camera.x -= 5;
    if( qKey_t.Push )Camera.y += 5;
    if( qKey_g.Push )Camera.y -= 5;
```

I'm out of ideas what I can try to make it work,
I was just trying feeding functions with different arguments.

//Edit1: I added two pictures here:

[When Camera is in its 0,0 Coords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrRmZ.png)
[image: When Camera is in its 0,0 Coords]

[When i move Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7X9n.png)
[image: When i move Camera]

Comment: I think the basic problem is a misunderstanding of vectors. But first, what do the things in the images represent? The upper left corner of the red rectangle is the player, and the purple circle is the mouse, is that correct? And the green line indicates the direction of looking? Where is the camera?

Comment: Two points do not define an angle.  Three do, but not two.  Two points defines a line, that is all.

Comment: Where does `qGetAngle2` come from and how is it defined? Instead of computing the angle between two vectors, it sounds as if you would want to compute an angle from cartesian coordinates. This is what [atan2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) does. Camera position should be irrelevant to the angle between any other two objects.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library provides [atan2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2). It returns the shortest angle in radians from the positive x-axis to a point in carthesian coordinates.

As the point is relative to the origin, you need to transform your coordinate system. Sounds scary, but in non-rotated 2D coordinates, you only need to subtract your reference point.

The following code will give you the angle from Shelly to the mouse pointer:

```cpp
constexpr auto r2d = 180. / M_PI;
qAngle = r2d * std::atan2(Shelly.y - qMouse.y, Shelly.x - qMouse.x);
```

Edit: I did provide a conversion from rad to degrees in my code snippet. However, using radians consistently is IMHO the better approach. Conversion should only take place before printing or logging an angle.